# How to check for IE in JavaScript when the code contains async/await

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, async-await, feature-detection

I've written JavaScript that contains async/await and I need to add a check to ensure the user is not using Internet Explorer.

Unfortunately, the use of async anywhere in the file causes the page to error and so the feature detection check I'm trying to use (checking for getUserMedia support) never fires.

I have no access to the page that the JavaScript will be added to, so I can't use conditional HTML comments.

How can I run my feature detection and display a message to the user if there is code in the file that uses async/await?

Comment: If you can't change the page to load the JS conditionally, you need to transpile it so that older browsers can load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the offending functions and placing them in another file and loading them after determining if the user is using an unsupported browser.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. You could mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer for 48 hours after the post date. Got another 23 hours to go!